# why does my network disconnects from internet every couple of hours?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I have a broadband [that here you can see its details.](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=3859&CURRENT_CMD=SEARCH&CONFIGURATION=1001&PARTITION_ID=1&USERTYPE=1&LANGUAGE=en&COUNTY=us&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=Cable) It provides wireless and also I got two more routers that use them as access points. DHCP is disabled on them and these two routers work are set by static IPs.  Since the beginning, every few hours all connected devices disconnects for 1-2 minutes and reconnect again. It is like the main router restarts or something like that.  It does not matter what device is connected to what router.  Everything disconnects all together.

Clearly the main router is the problem but do you why that happens?

Comment: What happens when you use only the main router w/o the access points? Same issue?

Comment: No I remember I never had this problem before I add APs.

Comment: Why is the main router the issue?  Do both the APs lose clients?  It could easily be radio interference, i.e. a microwave, telephone, etc that could cause clients to fall off . . .

Comment: Does the web interface of the main router show up-time? (So you can see if it restarted). And is there a log in the web interface where you can see if something is wrong?

Comment: @ernie as all devices disconnects no matter what router they r connected to so I guess the main router is the problem. Do you know how can I know if it is radio interference ?!

Comment: @Rik Yh I have access to the web interface and it shows that the session time is 6 days, that means it did not restarted whenever devices got disconnected.  :/

Comment: First test I would do is try to switch one of the routers to a different channel, and see if that helps.  I know my AP was dropping connections regularly when I was on channel 1, but on channel 11, the connection is very stable . . .